# How can I use VIM to edit files from within CPrompt on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, vim, git

I was following a tutorial on how to use Git earlier. The instructor was using a Mac, and used a program called Nano to edit a file he made from the command line (or what it's called on a Mac.)

I am using Windows 8. I am using "Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails." At any rate, I thought I was out of luck on the snazzy Nano feature. However, I noticed CMD (the command prompt thing) has what I think is VIM as part of it. It came about as I tried to commit, and suddenly this VIM arose so I could edit the commit.

So my question is, can I use VIM to edit files the same way as someone with Nano could, thus it being an equivalent, of sorts? If so, how do I "call" this VIM in relation to a file to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Actually VIM is not part of CMD or Windows, but part of your GIT install.

You probably have a git-bash shell somewhere in your Programs menu which opens a special shell where you can use some unix commands.

The specific VIM version on my machine resides in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\share\vim\vim73
```

and is called vim.exe

Comment: You can also run `vim.exe` as config free portable in-console editor. Just extract the exe from ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim74w32.zip

Answer (score 0):

Well, vim and nano are both command-line text editors but the comparison ends there.

Vim is very special, see if there's a

```
vimtutor
```

command available and go through it to get the basics right.